# psql TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, psql

I have a trouble when I try to automatically generate pid

```
    CREATE TABLE players(
      pID SERIAL primary key,
      pName VARCHAR(90) not null
    );
```

and here is my function

```
    def addPlayer(name):
       conn = connect()
       cur = conn.cursor()
       cur.execute("INSERT INTO players(pName) VALUES(%s)",name)
       conn.commit()
```

and I call the function with

```
    addPlayer('Vera')
```

I keep getting the error that

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO players(pName) VALUES(%s)",name)
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I search for hours but still confused. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass a tuple or list as the second parameter to execute.

When having more than one replacement in the query the tuple looks "normal" like this: (name, age).

In your case you need to add a tuple with just one part. The short but a bit unusual way to write that is to use (name,) as second parameter.

thus:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO players(pName) VALUES(%s)",(name,))
```

Although it's more common to use ? as the replacement char which would look like this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO players(pName) VALUES(?)",(name,))
```

Comment: after I change my code, I get an error with "cur.execute("INSERT INTO players(pName) VALUES(?)",(name,))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ")" "  Could you give any advice on this error?

Comment: I don't have a postgres database around to test with. The exact code you posted in the comment above works for me using the sqlite engine. Are you sure you used exactly that code? Does it work better using %s instead of ?. Most of the postgres docs seem to use the %s as default parameter style. My postgres code uses the named %(name) parameter style, because that's the most powerful and most clear styles from [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)

Comment: after I change my code to cur.execute("INSERT INTO players(pName) VALUES(%s)",(name,)) , it works for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing string interpolation with query variables.

String interpolation:

```
name = "Ben"
print("Hello, my name is %s" % name)

names = ["Adam", "Ben", "Charlie"]
print("Hello, our names are %s, %s and %s" % names)
```

Query variables:

```
values = [name]
cur.execute("INSERT INTO players(pName) VALUES(?)", values)
```

So changing your comma to a `%` would pass the variable into the string and would work, but the other way sanitises the input, so you should use the second example as is.

Comment: at least with the sqlite implementation of the dbapi2 this will still fail with (for a 5 letter string in name):
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.

Comment: Because it unpacks the string? So you need to create a list of tuple for values?

Comment: Right. The api takes an tuple or list (likely also other iteratable types) of exactly the length needed to fill all parameters. Thus the slightly unusual looking single item tuple literal in my answer. Although is is pretty often seen in python code actually, because there are lots of similar situations.